# How to insert new line after N char count in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, algorithm

I have a string which may have new line '\n' char in it. Now I want to insert new line '\n' after every 4 (or N) chars in that string.

For example:

1)
INPUT: "I am John Doe."

OUTPUT: "I am\nJohn\nDoe"

In above example inserting '\n' after 4 char including space

2) 
INPUT: "I\nam John Doe"

OUTPUT: "I\nam J\nohn \nDoe"

In above example inserting space after 4 chars after first '\n' already present in the string

3)
INPUT: 12345\n67890

OUTPUT: 1234\n5\n6789\n0

4)
INPUT: "1234\n56\n78901"

OUTPUT: "1234\n56\n7890\n1"

So far I have created a function which inserts '\n' after every 4 chars *but it does not consider* '\n' if it is already present in the original string.

```
function addNewlines(str) {
  if (str.length >= 4) {
    var result = '';
    while (str.length > 0) {
      result += str.substring(0, 4) + '\n';
      str = str.substring(4);
    }
    return result;
  }
  return str;
}
```

I call this function on every keypress and pass the original string and get output and use it further. I hope you understand what I meant to say here. It should preserve the previously inserted new lines.

Let me know I can explain further. With more examples.

Comment: Please confirm your second example, The first inserted \n is after 5 characters, why? More examples would help also. I also find the * around the `\n` characters confusing, make the input and output exactly the strings you need.

Comment: I have removed the *. Please do not consider the quotes it is just to represent string.

Comment: Your description says you want to add a newline after *every* four characters (or four characters after an existing newline), but your examples show only a *single* newline added to the string. Which is it, only one newline added in total, or a newline after every four characters?

Comment: Thanks, but your second example output is still confusing, should there not be a `\n` before `Doe`? You also state "inserting space after 4 characters" : under what conditions?

Comment: Yes thanks for pointing out I have added \n before Doe.

Comment: HI Michael, Yes insert new line after every 4 chars but if a new line is already their then count after that \n

Comment: Shouldn't your first example have one more `\n` too? And what should this string be turned into: 'ABCD\nEFGH\nIJKL' - should it simply preserve the existing newlines, or add additional newlines? The reason we're all guessing is that you haven't written a complete specification. You need to explain what you want in every edge case and provide a comprehensive list of inputs and outputs.

Comment: Yes ABCD\nEFGH\nIJKL should preserve the existing lines, example modified. So in your example there is no need to insert new lines because new lines are already there after every 4 chars.

Comment: What should each of these strings turn into: '1234', '12345678'?

Comment: INPUT: '1234' OUTPUT: 1234\n  i.e. cursor should be in new line      INPUT: '12345678'   OUTPUT: 1234\n5678\n

Comment: Your example 1 says "I am John Doe." should become "I am\nJohn\nDoe". What happened to the space after "am"? What happened to the period after "Doe."?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30202/discussion-between-deepak-and-michael-geary)

Comment: Actually I have to sign off for the night - getting late! But HPB's solution is very much like what I was experimenting with, so I recommend it if it does the trick.

Comment: Yeah HPB's solution is looking good to me as well. Just testing/experimenting this approach.

Comment: If a "\n" already exists, should we count each 4th character from that point, and leave the substring to left untouched?

Comment: @GuyDavid No, We need to process left string as well .... INPUT: 12345\n67890 OUTPUT: 1234\n5\n6789\n0

Comment: @deepak I see, so I will update my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is my best guess as to what is being asked for :

```
function addNewLines (str) { 
      return str.replace (/(?!$|\n)([^\n]{4}(?!\n))/g, '$1\n');
}
```

Some test strings and their results :

```
 "I am John Doe.",   -> "I am\n Joh\nn Do\ne."
 "I\nam John Doe",   -> "I\nam J\nohn \nDoe"
 "12345\n67890",     -> "1234\n5\n6789\n0"
 "1234\n56\n78901",  -> "1234\n56\n7890\n1"
 "ABCD\nEFGH\nIJKL", -> "ABCD\nEFGH\nIJKL\n"
 "1234",             -> "1234\n"
 "12341234"          -> "1234\n1234\n"
```

For those of you for whom regular expressions are mysterious here is a breakdown:

```
   ---------------------------- (?!     Check that following character(s) are not                  
   |  -------------------------   $|\n  Beginning of string or a newline character                   
   |  |   --------------------- )                
   |  |  | -------------------- (       Start of capture group 1        
   |  |  ||  ------------------   [^\n] Any single character other than newline           
   |  |  ||  |   --------------   {4}   Previous element repeated exactly 4 times        
   |  |  ||  |   |  -----------   (?!   Check that following character(s) are not  
   |  |  ||  |   |  | ---------     \n  a newline    
   |  |  ||  |   |  | | -------   )     
   |  |  ||  |   |  | | |------ )       End of capture group 1  
   |  |  ||  |   |  | | || ---- /g      in replace causes all matches to be processed
   |  |  ||  |   |  | | || |
 /(?!$|\n)([^\n]{4}(?!\n))/g
```

Comment: Thanks. It returns expected results.

Answer (score 1):

```
function parseInput(str, char, length){
    var split = str.split(char),
        regex = RegExp('(.{' + length + '})','g');

    split[split.length-1] = split[split.length - 1].replace(regex, '$1' + char);
    return split.join(char);
}

console.log(parseInput("I am John Doe.", "\n", 4)); 
// output = "I am\n Joh\nn Do\ne."
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Split the string by "\n" str.split("\n"). You get an array of strings.
2. Do your additional parsing and manipulation checking the element length and putting the result in a new array *results*.
3. Join the strings using results.join("\n").

This will remove "\n" duplicates too if you avoid to append or prepend "\n" to *results* elements.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code:

```
function ngram_insert (n, ins, input)
{
    var output = "";
    var i = 0;

    while (i < strlen(input))
    {
        if (i > 0 && i % n == 0)
        {
            output += ins;
        }

        output += input[i];

        i++;
    }

    return output;
}
```

Test:

```
var output = ngram_insert (3, "\n", "This is a test.");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function f(n, ins, str) {

      if (str.length == 0)
            return "";

      var i = str.indexOf("\n"), len = str.length, newStr;
      if (i == -1) {
            i = 1;
            newStr = str[0];
      }
      else {
           newStr = str.substring(0, i + 1);
      }

      var k = 1;

      while (k + i < len) {
            newStr += str[k + i];

            if (k % n == 0) {
                  newStr += ins;
            }

            k++;
      }

      return newStr;
}
```

Calling `f(4, "\n", "I\nam John Doe");` returns `"I\nam J\nohn \nDoe"`